# Linking with gl3n Errors

Tags: opengl, d

When I try to link my minimal program

```
import gl3n.linalg;
pragma(lib, "gl3n");
void main(string args[]) {
}
```

against the OpenGL library `gl3n` as

```
dmd -debug -gc -unittest -D -Dd/home/per/.emacs.d/auto-builds/dmd/Debug-Boundscheck-Unittest/home/per/Work/cognia/ -w  ~/Work/cognia/t_opengl.d -of/home/per/.emacs.d/auto-builds/dmd/Debug-Boundscheck-Unittest/home/per/Work/cognia/t_opengl
```

it errors as

```
LANG=en dmd -debug -gc -unittest -D -Dd/home/per/.emacs.d/auto-builds/dmd/Debug-Boundscheck-Unittest/home/per/Work/cognia/ -w  ~/Work/cognia/t_opengl.d -of/home/per/.emacs.d/auto-builds/dmd/Debug-Boundscheck-Unittest/home/per/Work/cognia/t_opengl
/home/per/opt/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/dmd/bin/../lib/libgl3n.a(util.o): In function `no symbol':
gl3n/util.d:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `_Dmodule_ref'
/home/per/opt/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/dmd/bin/../lib/libgl3n.a(linalg.o): In function `no symbol':
gl3n/linalg.d:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `_Dmodule_ref'
/home/per/opt/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/dmd/bin/../lib/libgl3n.a(plane.o): In function `no symbol':
gl3n/plane.d:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `_Dmodule_ref'
/home/per/opt/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/dmd/bin/../lib/libgl3n.a(plane.o): In function `_D4gl3n5plane13__T6PlaneTTfZ6PlaneT8opEqualsMxFNaNbNfS4gl3n5plane13__T6PlaneTTfZ6PlaneTZb':
gl3n/plane.d:(.text._D4gl3n5plane13__T6PlaneTTfZ6PlaneT8opEqualsMxFNaNbNfS4gl3n5plane13__T6PlaneTTfZ6PlaneTZb+0x51): undefined reference to `_D4gl3n6linalg16__T6VectorTfVi3Z6Vector53__T8opEqualsTxS4gl3n6linalg16__T6VectorTfVi3Z6VectorZ8opEqualsMxFNaNbNfxS4gl3n6linalg16__T6VectorTfVi3Z6VectorZb'
/home/per/opt/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/dmd/bin/../lib/libgl3n.a(math.o): In function `no symbol':
gl3n/math.d:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `_Dmodule_ref'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

What is `_Dmodule_ref`?

Answer (score 1):

_Dmodule_ref is a special symbol in druntime. The problem here is most likely related to either a wrongly installed druntime or an object.d in the current working directory.

1) Does compiling hello world work? If not, might help to reinstall dmd/druntime/phobos.

2) Is there a file in the same directory as your gl3n app called object.d? If so, rename it or something since dmd can see it there and get confused, thinking you want it to act as a custom druntime.